# Pivot a data frame to show metrics on rows, and years in column in R for each group

Tags: r, tidyverse, pivot-table

I have the following data frame in R

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2018, 2018, 2019, 2019), 
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
  metric = c(100, 150, 150, 200), 
  metric_percent = c(0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4))
```

| year | group | metric | metric_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | A | 100 | 0.1 |
| 2018 | A | 150 | 0.2 |
| 2019 | B | 150 | 0.3 |
| 2019 | B | 200 | 0.4 |

When I ran the following code, the output creates two columns for headcount & year, and two columns for representation and year.

```
df |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year,
              values_from = c(headcount, representation))

# Output
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  group headcount_2018 headcount_2019 representation_2018 representation_2019
  <chr> <list>         <list>         <list>              <list>             
1 A     <dbl [2]>      <NULL>         <dbl [2]>           <NULL>             
2 B     <NULL>         <dbl [2]>      <NULL>              <dbl [2]>
```

In my real example I have several groups and metrics to display so I need to see the data in a table in order to see the evolution of each metric for each group.

This is how I'd like to display the data in a table (I'll use flextable or gt for formatting it)

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  metric = c("headcount", "representation", "headcount", "representation"),
  "2018" = c(100, .1, 150, 0.3),
  "2019" = c(150, 0.2, 200, 0.4))

df2
```

| group | metric | 2018 | 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | headcount | 100.0 | 150.0 |
| A | representation | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| B | headcount | 150.0 | 200.0 |
| B | representation | 0.3 | 0.4 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That will not work.  In df each group has only data for one year, whereas df2 contains data for both years for each group, i.e. it is impossible to reshape df into df2. And that's also the reason why you end up with list columns when running `pivot_wider`. Perhaps you should check your data.

Comment: They issue is that "headcount" and "representation" appear out of nowhere. In your original data, are all `metric` values "headcount" and all `metric_pct` values "representation"? If so, then I would suggest pivoting the data **longer** first, and renaming these to the desired values, "headcount" and "representation", and then pivot_wider on year.

Comment: Also, maybe there's a typo in your sample data? Your `group = "A"` is in 2018 only, and `group = "B"` is in 2019 only. Perhaps you meant to alternate the years, `year = c(2018, 2019, 2018, 2019)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stefan said in the comments your data as it is posted cannot be reshaped into the desired format. Only if this is your data

```
dat
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  year  group headcount representation
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>          <dbl>
1 2018  A           100            0.1
2 2019  A           150            0.2
3 2018  B           150            0.3
4 2019  B           200            0.4
```

it can be reshaped into the expected format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(year, group), names_to="metric") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=year, values_from=value)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  group metric         `2018` `2019`
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     headcount       100    150  
2 A     representation    0.1    0.2
3 B     headcount       150    200  
4 B     representation    0.3    0.4
```

##### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c("2018", "2019", "2018", "2019"), group = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B"), headcount = c(100, 150, 150, 200), representation = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.4)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a typo in your sample data, this is a good way to proceed:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2018, 2019, 2018, 2019), 
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
  metric = c(100, 150, 150, 200), 
  metric_percent = c(0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4))

df |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("metric"), names_to = "metric") |>
  mutate(
    metric = case_match(
      metric,
      "metric" ~ "headcount",
      "metric_percent" ~ "representation"
    )
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#   group metric         `2018` `2019`
#   <chr> <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A     headcount       100    150  
# 2 A     representation    0.1    0.2
# 3 B     headcount       150    200  
# 4 B     representation    0.3    0.4
```

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Thomas, it worked as I wanted!